# Stubbing the method "class" with OCMock

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ocmock

I'm new to OCMock, so I may have overlooked something simple, but my issue is that I can't seem to stub the method `class` on a mock I've created. Here's how I'm setting up part of my test:

```
//  Unit Test
id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[MySubClass class]];
[[[mock stub] andReturn:[MySubClass class]] class];
...
[someObject someMethodWithParam:mock];
...
```

Here's my implementation of `someMethodWithParam:`:

```
//  Implementation
- (void)someMethodWithParam:(MySuperClass *)param {
    [[param class] someClassMethod];
}
```

The problem is that `[param class]` returns `OCClassMockObject` instead of `MySubClass`. This results in an "unrecognized selector sent to class" error when `someClassMethod` is called. I've tried using a partial mock, but that didn't seem to help.

Edit:

Here's a simplified test that won't pass:

```
//  Unit Test
id mock = [OCMockObject mockForClass:[MySubClass class]];
[[[mock stub] andReturn:[MySubClass class]] class];
XCTAssertEqual([mock class], [MySubClass class], @"The mock's class should be MySubClass");
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at your `-someMethodWithParam:`. It not return anything. It's void. So this is wrong test for this method. You made mock which have to return something even if method can't return anything.
This test should looks like following:

```
MyClass object = [MyClass new]; /// instance of class which has someMethodWithParam: method
id mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:object];
[[mock expect] someClassMethod];

[mock someMethodWithParam:[OCMArg any]];
[mock verify];
```

In this method only what you can is test expectation. You can test if method in your method has been called. So you can test if when you call `-someMethodWithParam` method `-someClassMethod` has been called. That's all. And you have to create partial mock.

Comment: OCMockObject +mockForClass: will work here as well, to save you creating the object instance if your test doesn't need it.